# How to pass value of a const from one .js file to another in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-functional-component, use-state

I have two .js files wherein I am defining two different components: **A.js** and **B.js**. I have a constant named `value` defined in **B.js** which uses the **UseState** hook, so when I try to `import B` into **A.js** I want to access one constant defined in **B.js**. Here's my code for a better clarity.

**B.js**

```
import clickcomponent from ".../..xxx"
export function B(){
...
...
const[value, setvalue]= useState("");
...
...
return(
 <clickcomponent
    ...
    ...
    onClick={newValue => {
        setvalue(newValue ? newValue : []);
      }}
  />
);
}
```

**A.js**

```
import B from "B.js"
export default function A(){
...
...
return (
    <B/>
  );
 }
```

I want to access the value of const `value` defined in B.js in A.js. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a callback function in component A which receives value from B.

```
import B from "B.js"
export default function A(){

const receiveValue = (value) => {console.log("value received from B",value)}

return (
 <B receiveValue={receiveValue} />
);
}
```

Now in your B you have to call that callback function which you passed in props from A component and pass any value you want to pass.

```
import Clickcomponent from ".../..xxx"
export default function B(props){
return(
  <Clickcomponent onClick={() => {
    props.receiveValue(5);
  }}
 />
);
```

Note: also change your `import clickcomponent` to `import Clickcomponent` because component names first letter should be capital.

Comment: In console it shows: value received from B[object Object]

Comment: yes because in component B we were passing object. I have updated code and now i am passing number 5. Now it will be passed to component A and will be shown in console.

Comment: yes its just a function you can put any code in that.

Comment: I just did console.log to show that value is received by A.

Comment: You can do anything inside that function.

Comment: you can also do alert(value); instead of console.log

Comment: receiveValue = (value) => {console.log("value received from B"+value)}
But what if the above statement I want to use inside an async function/UseEffect then we cant access receiveValue within the same .js file only....

Comment: what will be the purpose of putting this statement in useEffect? Remember useEffect is similar to componentDidMount lifecycle method.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass down a callback from A, to B wherein A can have access to the component fully, while B still has the ability to access it. This is done through the concept of **props** in react.

#### Pseudo Code

#### A

```js
import B from "B.js"
export default function A() {
...
const[value, setvalue]= useState("");
return (
    <B callback={(value) => setvalue(value)}/>
  );
 }
```

#### B

```js
import clickcomponent from ".../..xxx"
export default function B(props){
...
...
return(
 <clickcomponent
    ...
    ...
    onClick={newValue => {
        props.callback(newValue ? newValue : []);
      }}
  />
);
}
```

Sandbox link for the visual effect [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-worker-zyv2s).

I hope this helps.

Comment: This was just pseudo code to help you. I'll attach a sandbox link now.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by lifting component B state up.

### B.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const B = ({ liftingStateUpHandler }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("You got me");

  return (
    <button onClick={() => liftingStateUpHandler(value)}>
      Click me to lift state up
    </button>
  );
};

export default B;
```

### A.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import B from "./B";

const A = () => {
  const [stateA, setStateA] = useState("");

  const getState = value => setStateA(value);

  return (
    <>
      <div>State from component B: {stateA}</div>
      <B liftingStateUpHandler={getState} />
    </>
  );
};

export default A;
```

Here is more about [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up) and example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-bash-q4kof).